# Is it possible to play local audio.mp3 not in assets - Mobile Flutter

Tags: flutter, audio

I have a big problem!

I have one Flutter Project that allow user record them voice, save file in local and listen after.

The file is saved properly, path is like:

```
/data/user/0/com.example.login/app_flutter/record/record_2023-11-15 07:50:02.167981Z.mp3
```

When I find some solutions to play these audios, every flutter audio player package only support file in "assets", but this folder read-only, seem like project lib.

I've found this package: `audioplayers`, it supports play Uint8list, but not working.

So, is it possible to play local audio.mp3 not in assets?

Thank you!

Comment: https://pub.dev/documentation/audioplayers/latest/audioplayers/DeviceFileSource-class.html